# Determine filesystem type by directory

Tags: android, busybox

I launch this command via Process to determine the file system of specific directory.

```
stat -f -c %T path
```

Unfortunately the output is not reliable.
For example

```
$ stat -f -c %T /                                    
romfs
$ stat -f -c %T /sdcard/                             
UNKNOWN
$ stat -f -c %T /mnt/external_sd/                    
msdos
```

The [Partition Table](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cls.partition) app from the Google Play shows valid names like "ext4", "yaffs" and "vfat". How can I achieve that?
Note: I rely on busybox so no problem with lacking tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use `mount`? You just have to determine in which partition is your directory.

Comment: For `FAT32` or `exFAT` `mount` always return: `type fuse`

Comment: Yes, there are FUSE drivers for microsoft filesystems, e.g. https://packages.debian.org/sid/fusefat. But even on phone with aosp 8 is vfat kernel module used.

Comment: So via `mount` you cannot determine file system.